# Generated PDF displaying empty pages

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm writing a PDF generator for an embedded system and i can't seem to get it to render. Here's what i have so far http://pastebin.com/20DQiGfb.
Neither ghostscript, nor RUPS is showing any syntax errors, and every PDF viewer i checked this on displays blank pages. I'v verified the syntax, offsets, structure to be fine. I just don't get it.
Maybe someone can suggest another tool i can try ? Maybe one that would let me inspect the visual elements ?

EDIT: adding the full file for download https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ljtiq-2gIJcTBFR2tjRGxVOFk/view?usp=sharing

EDIT2: Acrobat/Preflight also found no errors

Comment: Can you post a downloadable version of this PDF file? That would allow us to look at the actual structure and open it in some diagnostic tools to see what messages it shows...

Comment: here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ljtiq-2gIJcTBFR2tjRGxVOFk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are your **Page** dictionaries:

```
7 0 obj
<<  /Type      /Page         
    /Parent    9 0 R        
    /Resources 2 0 R        
    /Content   3 0 R        
    /MediaBox  [0 0 612 792] 
>>
endobj

8 0 obj
<<  /Type      /Page         
    /Parent    9 0 R        
    /Resources 2 0 R        
    /Content   5 0 R        
    /MediaBox  [0 0 612 792] 
>>
endobj
```

But the correct key for the content stream is **Contents**!

> **Contents** stream or array *(Optional)* A content stream (see 7.8.2, "Content Streams") that shall describe the contents of this page. If this entry is absent, the page shall be empty.
>
> *(Table 30 – Entries in a page object - [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

After adding the missing `s` characters I see:

[image: page 1]

and

[image: page 2]

Comment: That was it, I can't believe a simple type caused me so much grief :S

Comment: If the answer works for you, please accept it (click the tick on its left)

Comment: sorry about that, forgot